# Adding a line plot to a barplot - line dots not in centre of the bars

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to add a simple line plot to an `barplot` using this code:

```
mp <- barplot(monatsdurchschnitt_niederschlag, ylim = c(0, 90));
mp
#      [,1]
# [1,]  0.7
# [2,]  1.9
# [3,]  3.1
# [4,]  4.3
# [5,]  5.5
# [6,]  6.7
# [7,]  7.9
# [8,]  9.1
# [9,] 10.3
#[10,] 11.5
#[11,] 12.7
#[12,] 13.9

axis(1, at=mp[,1], labels = xlabels_monate)
text(mp[,1], monatsdurchschnitt_niederschlag,
     labels = monatsdurchschnitt_niederschlag_rounded,
     pos = 3, cex = 1)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(mp[,1], monatsdurchschnitt, col = "red", axes=FALSE, type = "o",
     ylim = c(0,40), xlim = c(0,14), ann = FALSE)
axis(4, at=seq(0,40,10), ylim = c(0,40), col = "red", col.axis = "red")
```

[image]

But somehow, the dots of the 2nd line plot aren't centred in the bars of the bar-plot, as you can clearly see. I thought that would be solved by using `mp[,1]` as x-coordinates for the line plot, but obviously this didn't work out. Does anyone know a solution to that?

Another matter would be that the axis of the additional line plot on the right doesn't start at the same height as the axis on the left. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`par(new = TRUE)` is the source of problem. Can't you use `lines` instead of `plot` for drawing the red line?

If not, make sure you have the same `xlim` between two `plot`. How about explicitly setting `xlim = extendrange(mp, f = 0.1)` in both `plot`? Right now you did not specify `xlim` in `barplot`, but set `xlim = c(0, 14)` in your second `plot`. The difference in `xlim` will cause misalignment problem.

Comment: adding xlim for the barplot actually worked out, thanks! I didn't use `lines`, since it would be scaled to the original scale on the left side and I want it a bit bigger, as it is in the shown image. Is there a way to "upscale" it when using `lines`? This way I wouldn't have to deal with the displacement of the right scale...